# Can't add child to WrapPanel from another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm new to threading tasks so it may be obvious why I can't do what I'm doing. I don't understand why I can change the `Width` of the `WrapPanel` in my thread, but I can't add a child to it. Here is my code:

```
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Thread t = new Thread(LoadIcons);
     t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

     t.Start();
}

private void LoadIcons()
{ 
     Foreach(icon present in directory)
     {
        Icon icon = new Icon { Width = 16, Height = 16};

        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => pnlIcons.Width = 50)); //Will let me
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => pnlIcons.Children.Add(icon))); // Won't
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can't because you're created `Icon` in different thread. You need to create it inside the delegate itself. Not sure what you're trying to achieve and why do you need a new thread here.

Comment: This process takes 5 - 10 seconds and so the the user can't interact wit the UI at all. I was hoping doing this would mean the UI wouldn't locked for this time. Is this not true?

Comment: Which process takes  5 - 10 seconds? You're not showing that code here. Also what is that `Icon`?

Comment: I've stripped the LoadIcons method of superfluouse code as it's sensitive. But it does a little more to the icon than just set it's height/width. There are also A LOT of icons in the directory.

Comment: Load elements in UI isn't an easy task. Calling to pnlIcons.Children.Add() adds element to the visual tree of your WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must rewrite your code. Put the *icon* inside the Dispatcher in order to avoid exceptions.

```
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(LoadIcons);
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

    t.Start();
}

private void LoadIcons()
{ 
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => 
    {
        foreach(Icon present in directory)
        { 
            present.Width = 16;
            present.Height = 16;
            pnlIcons.Width = 50;
            pnlIcons.Children.Add(present);
        }
    }));
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That will prevent the exception, but why? Why do you need a new thread if you're simply going to call `Dispatcher.Invoke`? Completely insane.

Comment: Ah, I clearly need to do some more research into this. Thank you, my UI now stays active and I can watch as the icon load in one by one!

Comment: @Sriram Load elements in UI isn't an easy task. Calling to pnlIcons.Children.Add() adds element to the visual tree of your WPF.

Comment: @ChristianAmado So? What's your point? Are you aware that `Dispatcher.Invoke` will invoke the delegate in UI thread? How that's different from not at all using new `Thread` ?